# Ошибка при компиляции dwm - не найден заголовочный файл

Tags: linux, gcc, gnumake

При компиляции `dwm6.1` появляется следующая ошибка:

```
eanmos@pc:~/documents/dwm-6.1$ sudo make install 
dwm build options:
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Os  -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2 -DVERSION="6.1" -DXINERAMA
LDFLAGS  = -s 
CC       = cc
CC drw.c
In file included from drw.c:6:0:
/usr/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h:39:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'drw.o' failed
make: *** [drw.o] Error 1
```

`xlibxinerama-dev, libxft-dev, libfreetype6-dev` установлены.
Файл `ft2build.h` присутствует в папке `/usr/include/freetype2/`

Содержимое файла `config.mk`:

```
# dwm version
VERSION = 6.1

# Customize below to fit your system

# paths
PREFIX = /usr/local
MANPREFIX = ${PREFIX}/share/man

X11INC = /usr/X11R6/include
X11LIB = /usr/X11R6/lib

# Xinerama, comment if you don't want it
XINERAMALIBS  = -lXinerama
XINERAMAFLAGS = -DXINERAMA

# freetype
FREETYPELIBS = -lfontconfig -lXft
FREETYPEINC = /usr/include/freetype2/
# OpenBSD (uncomment)
FREETYPEINC = ${X11INC}/freetype2

# includes and libs
+INCS = -I${X11INC} -I/usr/include/freetype2 
+LIBS = -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} -lutil -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig

# flags
CPPFLAGS = -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2 -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\" ${XINERAMAFLAGS}
#CFLAGS   = -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -O0 ${INCS} ${CPPFLAGS}
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Os ${INCS} ${CPPFLAGS}
LDFLAGS  = -s ${LIBS}

# Solaris
#CFLAGS = -fast ${INCS} -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\"
#LDFLAGS = ${LIBS}

# compiler and linker
CC = cc
```

Содержимое фалйа `Makefile`:

```
# dwm - dynamic window manager
# See LICENSE file for copyright and license details.

include config.mk

SRC = drw.c dwm.c util.c
OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}

all: options dwm

options:
    @echo dwm build options:
    @echo "CFLAGS   = ${CFLAGS}"
    @echo "LDFLAGS  = ${LDFLAGS}"
    @echo "CC       = ${CC}"

.c.o:
    @echo CC $<
    @${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $<

${OBJ}: config.h config.mk

config.h:
    @echo creating $@ from config.def.h
    @cp config.def.h $@

dwm: ${OBJ}
    @echo CC -o $@
    @${CC} -o $@ ${OBJ} ${LDFLAGS}

clean:
    @echo cleaning
    @rm -f dwm ${OBJ} dwm-${VERSION}.tar.gz

dist: clean
    @echo creating dist tarball
    @mkdir -p dwm-${VERSION}
    @cp -R LICENSE TODO BUGS Makefile README config.def.h config.mk \
        dwm.1 drw.h util.h ${SRC} dwm.png transient.c dwm-${VERSION}
    @tar -cf dwm-${VERSION}.tar dwm-${VERSION}
    @gzip dwm-${VERSION}.tar
    @rm -rf dwm-${VERSION}

install: all
    @echo installing executable file to ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin
    @mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin
    @cp -f dwm ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin
    @chmod 755 ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin/dwm
    @echo installing manual page to ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1
    @mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1
    @sed "s/VERSION/${VERSION}/g" < dwm.1 > ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1/dwm.1
    @chmod 644 ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1/dwm.1

uninstall:
    @echo removing executable file from ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin
    @rm -f ${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin/dwm
    @echo removing manual page from ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1
    @rm -f ${DESTDIR}${MANPREFIX}/man1/dwm.1

.PHONY: all options clean dist install uninstall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> +INCS = -I${X11INC} -I/usr/include/freetype2 
> +LIBS = -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} -lutil -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig
> ```

здесь явная смысловая ошибка — ведь в дальнейшем используются перменные `INCS` и `LIBS`, а не `+INCS` и `+LIBS` (да, в *gnu/make* это — допустимые имена перменных).

скорее всего тот, кто писал эти строки, хотел **добавить** информацию **к** значениям переменных с помощью оператора `+=`:

```
INCS += -I${X11INC} -I/usr/include/freetype2 
LIBS += -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} -lutil -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig
```

---

иллюстрация описанного:

```
переменная = начальное значение
переменная += добавка
+переменная = хитрое имя переменной

цель:
    @echo $(переменная)
    @echo $(+переменная)
```

при вызове *make* выведет:

> начальное значение добавка
>   хитрое имя переменной

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!